# Age Bracket display with google bar chart PHP Mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-visualization

need help. Here's the thing, I want to make a chart, specifically a Google Bar graph which displays the age bracket of a group of people. It should display the number of people within that age bracket. Btw I'm using PHP MySql. Thanks in advance!

Update. I found some something on this page. This is the current query:

```sql
SELECT evacuee_age, COUNT(*) as `count`
FROM
tbl_evacuee
INNER JOIN (
 SELECT 
     0 , 12, '0-12' as `group`
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT
     13, 14, '13-14'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT
     15, 19, '15-19'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT
     20, 150, '20+'
) `sub`
GROUP BY `group`;
```

google chart code...

```
  function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Age', 'Evacuees', { role: 'style' } ],
      <?php  
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run))  {  
                echo "['".$row["evacuee_age"]."', ".$row["count"]."],";
           }  
      ?>  
  ]);
```

Comment:  This is an “I want a pony” type of question that’s difficult to answer concisely and is off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you can, make an attempt and then show us your code we can understand what you’re trying to do on a technical level. Even a small amount of code, however incomplete or broken, can give us context and illustrate your intentions. Instead of leaving us to speculate on what you might need, give us something to build so we can focus help in those areas where it’s most needed.

Comment: Hi. I posted the current code. I hope it could help to answer my problem. Thanks

Comment: Tip: Don't bash together your own JSON. Use [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Comment: What is the *technical problem* you're having? This is just code. Do you get errors?

Comment: Hmm. The php and javascript are in one file. The problem is, it doesn't show anything.

Comment: When you say "doesn't show anything" do you mean "it doesn't render any HTML" or do you mean "the graph doesn't show up"? **Do you get any HTML output or JavaScript errors**? Please, look at the HTML source. Look at your JavaScript console. Pay attention to these when working on your app.

Comment: The graph doesn't show up. I think my query is wrong?

Comment: Update: It already show something. But the result is not what I expected. I think there is something wrong with my query.

Comment: Break this down into parts. A) Does the query run by itself produce useful output? B) Can you properly encode that output into the JSON value? C) Does the JavaScript work correctly on that data?